# Copy/paste files from one directory to another

Tags: bash, copy, copy-paste

can  you please tell me what is wrong with my simple code? (Mac Bash)

I am trying to copy all files that are called vol_0000.nii from one directory to another. I replaced the variable file name with '*'. All files (vol_0000.nii) have the same name but they are in different folders (Indicated by '*'). Im not sure whether when they are being copied they are replacing each other since they have the same name of the cp creates, for example, vol_00001.nii, vol_00002.nii and so on..?

```
cp /Users/dave/biomkr/dat/*/rs/orig/vol_0000.nii /Users/dave/Documents/MIT_Har_stu/rsfmri
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12187859/3076724) is probably on point

Comment: So aside from the number problem, should my code work if the Vol have different numbers?

Comment: Yes, let's say you have `/Users/dave/biomkr/dat/a/rs/orig/vol_0000.nii` and `/Users/dave/biomkr/dat/b/rs/orig/vol_0000.nii`, doing  `cp /Users/dave/biomkr/dat/*/rs/orig/vol_0000.nii /Users/dave/Documents/MIT_Har_stu/rsfmri` will expand to `cp /Users/dave/biomkr/dat/a/rs/orig/vol_0000.nii /Users/dave/biomkr/dat/b/rs/orig/vol_0000.nii /Users/dave/Documents/MIT_Har_stu/rsfmri` (`a`,`b`, order may be switched) which will first copy the file in `a` to `rsfmri` and then overwite it with the one in `b`. You could `do cp -iv`, which will prompt you if you want to overwrite and make it more verbose

Comment: Yes, cp sorry!
Ok ill try the cp -iv. Thanks!

Comment: wow, it did ask me, but i tried with only 500 files and said not to overwrite but it didn't work!!! After finishing all those Nos and the message saying not overwritten, i opened the destination file to find only one vol!!!

Comment: Yes, I meant that would make it more obvious/verbose what it's doing. `cp` does not have an option to automatically rename files if it finds a duplicate, you will need to do it in a script, similar the initial link I added

Comment: Dope! Sorry, i understand...

Comment: Actually try `cp --backup=t`, per http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17293/60101. If your version of `cp` supports it (newest `gnu` does, not sure about `mac`/`bsd`), that should create backups like `vol_0000.nii vol_0000.nii~ vol_0000.nii.~1~ vol_0000.nii.~2~`, etc...

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job, using a similar numbering behaviour to that which you mentioned in your question.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
for src in /Users/dave/biomkr/dat/*/rs/orig/vol_0000.nii
do
    dest=$(basename "$src")
    dest=${dest/.nii/_$i.nii}
    cp "$src" "/Users/dave/Documents/MIT_Har_stu/rsfmri/$dest"
    let i++
done
```

Another option is to create a subdirectory, based on the directory name substituted for `*` in the original glob, which we can get with a little [string replacement](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

```
#!/bin/bash
for src in /Users/dave/biomkr/dat/*/rs/orig/vol_0000.nii
do
    srcdir=${src#/Users/dave/biomkr/dat/}
    srcdir=${srcdir%/rs/orig/vol_0000.nii}
    srcdir="/Users/dave/Documents/MIT_Har_stu/rsfmri/$srcdir/"
    mkdir -p "$srcdir"
    cp "$src" "$srcdir"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. The first one gave no error but the output is only one vol file!
Will try the second. 
In addition the output is vol_0000.nii.0> Which is different than i wanted. This one changes the actual extension. the output col looks different than the original vol file!

Comment: Ok i changed the last part to "$dest_$i.nii" and it worked!
Thanks, ill up vote you as soon as i have enough reputations! :)

Comment: Glad to help. You can mark the answer as accepted at any reputation level. This indicates the question is closed, and will also give you some rep.