# How to automate if/else/then tasks in shell/bash in this context?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, if-statement

So to give context, let's say that I'm running a script that is creating a file with the title "name1.file", now I'm trying to figure how I would do this:

Execute the command, generate "name1.file", however if I was to run the command again, **if** "name1.file" is found, to generate "name2.file"- however I cannot figure out how to automate this process so it would continue on to name3.file, name4.file and vice versa...

How could this be achieved?

Using Ubuntu 16.04 server, this is a bash/shell script (.sh)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187859/create-new-file-but-add-number-if-filename-already-exists-in-bash

Comment: `c=1; while [[ -f name${c}.file ]]; do c=$((c+=1)); done; touch name${c}.file`?

Comment: @Cyrus I\`d change `c=$((c+=1))` to `((c++))`.

Comment: @hidefromkgb: Thank you. Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this:

```
# get the "maximum" file:
max=$(printf "%s\n" name*.file | sort --version-sort | tail -n 1)

# find the "file number"
[[ $max =~ name([0-9]+)\.file ]] && num=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

# the next file
new_file="name$((num+1)).file"
```